# Setting up Task Constraints

Tags: azure-batch

How can I go about setting the max task retry count and the max task wall clock time for a task in Azure Batch?

I tried the following:

```
task.Constraints.MaxTaskRetryCount = 3;
task.Constraints.MaxWallClockTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
```

But this didn't seem to work as it breaks the code in that the task is then never created. What could possibly be the problem? What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume you're setting this on the CloudTask before adding them to the job. What do you mean when you say it breaks the code?

Comment: @fpark Yes, I was setting them when defining the CloudTask and not after the CloudTask was added to the job, would that be the problem? Break might be a strong word, but what I meant is that the job exits as complete without even creating the tasks that I set those constraints on.

Comment: Are you setting an [OnAllTasksComplete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.batch.cloudjob.onalltaskscomplete?view=azurebatch-7.0.1#Microsoft_Azure_Batch_CloudJob_OnAllTasksComplete) property?

Comment: @fpark No. I am adding my tasks through the job manager task

Comment: @fpark Any ideas of how to set up this successfully?

Comment: I don't have your entire code so I don't know what's going on. But generally you would add a constraint on the [`TaskAddParameter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.batch.protocol.models.taskaddparameter?view=azurebatch-7.0.1), e.g.: `new TaskAddParameter(id: taskId, commandLine: "cmd /c dir", constraints: new TaskConstraints(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10), null, 3))`

Comment: @fpark I am not using TaskAddParameter class. I am using the CloudTask class as follows: `CloudTask task = new CloudTask(taskID, commandLine)`. Is there a way to make it work with CloudTask class?

Comment: You should be able to do the same thing with CloudTask (and my error, you should use CloudTask), although that would be no different than what you have above. Are you sure that you are calling add task on the job? I don't know what else could be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it using TaskConstraints object 
For eg :

```
CloudTask task = new CloudTask(taskId, taskCommandLine);
TaskConstraints taskConstraints = new TaskConstraints();
taskConstraints.MaxTaskRetryCount = 3;
taskConstraints.MaxWallClockTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
task.Constraints = taskConstraints;
```